# Why use sizeof(int) in a malloc call?

Tags: malloc

I am new to C++ and also in MPI programming. I have confused about this code block in C++

```
int count;
count=4;
local_array=(int*)malloc(count*sizeof(int));
```

Why are we using `sizeof(int)` here in MPI programming?

Comment: This code is allocating a block of memory that will hold 4 values of type `int`.  `sizeof(int)` tells you how many bytes of memory are required to store a single value of type `int`.

Comment: if local_array is declared as 'int*', you will use sizeof(int).

Comment: Note that `malloc` is more a C construct than a C++ construct. If you want to be running your code in a C++ manner, you should look into the STL options available (such as `std::vector`) or at the least allocate your memory on the heap using `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see that you're trying to allocate 4 `int`s here.

If you look at `malloc`'s signature, it takes the number of bytes for its first parameter. As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx), `int` data type takes 4 bytes.

Therefore, if you want 4 `int`s, you could have typed `local_array=(int*)malloc(count*4);`. But not everyone remembers that `int` actualy takes 4 bytes. That's why you use `sizeof` to find out the actual size of the object or type.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, If we allocate array in C++ we mention how many byte we need, In this code we allocate 4 integers, so we need 4 * size of one integer all together 4 bytes * 4 = 16 bytes that's why we use sizeof(int) to getting one integer size. Am i right?

Comment: Absolutely. Glad that I could help

Comment: "not everyone remembers that `int` actualy takes 4 bytes" - sometimes, it doesn't! It could be 2, or 8, or 1, or some other value.

Comment: That's true. Some machine might have different sizes for `int`. But according to the documentation I was referring to, it says 4 bytes. So, to eliminate complexity and to make it easier for OP to understand, I'm just gonna generalize it to 4 bytes.